# How do I resize Images using python code?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working to resize a bundle of images using python code i.e. "Resize.py". But I am getting the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\NAJEEB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2205, in thumbnail
    if x > size[0]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the code:

```
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import glob

pathIn = 'F:/prac'
pathOut = 'F:/prac'
name = 'resize.py'
newsize = 300*300
int_desiredLength = 3

if not os.path.exists(pathOut):
os.makedirs(pathOut)
for i, file in enumerate(glob.glob(pathIn + '/*')):

fname = name + '_{str_0:0>{str_1}}.jpg'.format(str_0=i+1, str_1=int_desiredLength)
im = Image.open(file)
im.thumbnail((newsize), Image.ANTIALIAS)
apparent_size = im.size
apparent_h, apparent_w = im.size
desired_h, desired_w = newsize
delt_h, delt_w = abs(apparent_h - desired_h), abs(apparent_w - desired_w)

padding = (delt_h // 2, delt_w // 2, delt_h - (delt_h // 2), delt_w - (delt_w // 2))
im = ImageOps.expand(im, padding)
desired_size = im.size
print('{0}: {1}====>{2}'.format(fname, apparent_size, desired_size))
im.save(os.path.join(pathOut, fname))
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code to SO. Can you copy/paste and then format the code via editing please?

Comment: always put code, data and error mesage as text, not link to external page or image.

Comment: it seems your `size` has only one value, not tuple or list, and you can't use `[0]`. Simply use `print(size)` to see what you have in this variable.

Comment: sure I will edit my post

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Post the code please so we can copy and try

Comment: The problem is you should change `newsize` to `(300,300)` not `300*300`

Comment: It's width,height & the total pixels are width*height, if you provide the total pixels only like 300*300, what do you expect the shape of the image to be?

Comment: Thanks Everyone! size= (300,300) works for me. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `size = 300*300`

The pil thumbnail api requires size to be 2 element **tuple** so use

```
size = (300, 300)
```